# How to iterate through a list, print out the value of the iteration, and stop when a user wants

Tags: list, loops

I am just starting python out and I cant figure this one out. I am completely lost at the moment and not sure how to even start this, hopefully someone can help.

Print the integers of the list `[2, 6, 4, 3, 7]` so that the program asks after every number `do you want to print the next number (y/n)?` and the program terminates when user inputs `n`.

Here is what I gave tried:

```
list = 2, 6, 4, 3, 7
n = int(input('Do you want to print the next number y/n?'))
```

and from there I am stuck, I can't figure out how to move forwards.

Comment: Your issue is that you are not iterating the options and allowing a break of the loop. You also are asking for `y` or `n` and casting to an `int()` which, unless the user executing the program doesn't follow the instructions, would cause an exception. Lists in python are defined in brackets as well. For example: `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` not like: `my_list = 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you need to loop your list and `break` out of it. Here is one example:

```
for item in [2, 6, 4, 3, 7]:
    print(item)
    keep_going = input('do you want to print the next number? y/n')
    if keep_going.lower() == 'n':
        print('you opted to exit')
        break # exit the loop
    else:
        # just continue the loop
        # to do this you can remove else, add pass, or use continue
        continue
```

One other way is to wrap the inner loop in an `exitable` while loop and breaking out when the user hits `n`. Although this is another option, it seems like overkill due to double iteration.

For example:

```
exit = False
while exit is False:
    for item in [2, 6, 4, 3, 7]:
        print(item)
        keep_going = input('do you want to print the next number? y/n')
        if keep_going.lower() == 'n':
            print('you opted to exit')
            exit = True # exit outer loop
            break # break innerloop
        else:
            # just continue the loop
            # to do this you can remove else, add pass, or use continue
            continue
```